# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: while installing pandas in OSGeo4W Shell

Tags: python, pandas, installation, osgeo

I have instantiated osgeo4w with run as administrator, still it gives me Permission denied.
I am trying to install pandas on Quantum GIS 2.8, I have installed sklearn with the pip command and it got installed sucessfully.

But when I am trying to install pandas it gives the error as following :

```
  C:\Windows\System32>pip install pandas
    Collecting pandas
    C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
      SNIMissingWarning
    C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
      InsecurePlatformWarning
      Using cached pandas-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in c:\progra~1\qgiswi~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg (from pandas)
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg (from pandas)
    Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas)
      Using cached numpy-1.10.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg (from python-dateutil->pandas)
    Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 732, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 835, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 322, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\multiarray.pyd'
```

Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone (like me) find this post useful...

I had the very same issue when upgrading pandas from 0.18 to 0.20 when doing
`pip install --upgrade pandas`.

The problem: numpy and pandas installers want to write newer files which exist already in ../site-packages/numpy and ../site-packages/pandas folders.

For some reason, shutil fails to open those files in 'wb' mode.

Although the requirement `numpy>=1.7.0` was satisfied, using "--upgrade" lead to upgrade numpy as well.

**Solution:**

In order to avoid `IO Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...`, uninstall both numpy and pandas, then pursue with re-installation (numpy being first):

```
    pip uninstall numpy
    pip install numpy
    pip uninstall pandas
    pip install pandas
```